# Filtering Lucene result AND NOT

Tags: lucene

I'm trying to filter out a number of items from a query result.

The end result should only contain results that have Private set to false or if true, are part of a supplied Privacy group

Let's say the basic query result is this

```
ID  Name    Private PrivacyGroup
1   Yellow  false   
2   Red     true    1
3   Blue    true    2
4   Orange  true    1
5   Black   false
6   Green   true    3
```

I've tried a variety of filters, but this seems to be one that I think should work and it isn't:

```
BooleanQuery bq = new BooleanQuery();       

BooleanQuery privacyQuery  = new BooleanQuery();
BooleanQuery privacyFinalQuery  = new BooleanQuery();

privacyFinalQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term("Private", "true")),Occur.MUST);

for(String i : suppliedGroups){
privacyQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term("PrivacyGroup", i)), Occur.SHOULD);
}

privacyFinalQuery.add(groupQuery, Occur.MUST_NOT);

bq.add(privacyFinalQuery, Occur.MUST_NOT);

return new CachingWrapperFilter(new QueryWrapperFilter(bq));
```

This leads to

```
(-(+Private:true -(PrivacyGroup:1 PrivacyGroup:2)))
```

The end result is 0 results, and I would expect: 1,2,3,4,5

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is fully negative and really doesn't match any document.

You should add `MatchAllDocsQuery` as a first clause and further filter it by provided negative query.

Try to add following line:

```
bq.add(new MatchAllDocsQuery(), Occur.MUST);
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefacing a pure negative query with a `MatchAllDocsQuery` works, yes.  It performs extremely poorly, but it does the job.

It seems that constructing your query the same way you stated your problem would lead to the much simpler, less hacky, implementation though:

> Private set to false or if true, are part of a supplied Privacy group

So, you want private=false or group=1 or group=2, which could be put more simply as:

```
(Private:false PrivacyGroup:1 PrivacyGroup:2)
```

Or,

```
BooleanQuery privacyQuery  = new BooleanQuery();

privacyQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term("Private", "false")),Occur.SHOULD);

for(String i : suppliedGroups){
    privacyQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term("PrivacyGroup", i)), Occur.SHOULD);
}

return new CachingWrapperFilter(new QueryWrapperFilter(privacyQuery));
```

Comment: Yes, it is a very good variant, but BQ is properly optimized and skipping big unmatched regions of any query part using `advance` function. So I can't make performance  difference estimation without tests.

Comment: @Nikolay I'm not aware of any performance optimizations in lucene that make queries like `MatchAllDocsQuery -term` performant.  Could you direct me to documentation of that feature?

Comment: There must be a better way to filter content than using the matchalldocsquery? I like the filtering approach because it guarantees a level of security. If I make a mistake in the query process, I can guarantee that certain content simply doesn't show up

Comment: I believe the code I posted returns an appropriate filter without relying on a match all.